# JavaScript to add/remove back button in Qualtrics

Tags: javascript, qualtrics

I am trying to use the code hidePreviousButton () to hide the back button in Qualtrics. Currently, I have added the back button on all questions using the Survey Options, and I would like to remove the back button on certain pages.

If there is not a way to do that, then I would be equally open to **adding** the back button on select pages using JavaScript as well.

Thank you for any assistance!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What research have you made? Be sure to check out [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: use: this.hidePreviousButton ()

Answer (score 1):

To hide the previous button, you can use: 
    `this.hidePreviousButton ()`

So the full code screen should look like this:

```
`Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{
this.hidePreviousButton () 
});
`
```

I found this in the API Qualtrics page, but there it forgets to tell you that you need to include "this." before any of the commands that it gives you. At least, adding that code before the command worked for the ones I tried.

Answer (score 0):

The API page for Qualtrics is actually inaccurate, unfortunately it needs a few updates. The current way to do this, is by adding:

```
$('.PreviousButton').hide();
```

to the JavaScript for any question you want to hide it for.